# How to enter the Django shell in read-only mode?

Tags: mysql, django

I'm interested in using a form of the Django shell which only permits read operations. So far, I've read this blog article (https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2012/12/21/read-only-django-shell.html), which seems to be based on setting `django.db.router.db_for_write` to `None`.

Is this the recommended way to do this? As I understand from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers, the `django.db.router` is the 'master router' and it is not clear to me whether I can modify its attributes without affecting the environment in which the database is running.

Perhaps there is another way, like creating a database (in my case, MySQL) user with only read permission, and starting a Django shell connected as that user?

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly trickier than one might anticipate because it sounds like you'll need a separate set of settings to use for the `shell` command versus normal django operation.  So three step process:

1. create your own router class
2. create a separate settings file to be used with the `shell` command
3. use an environment variable or a separate `manage.py` to run the `shell` command